# Phonegap Dev App not appearing in chrome remote debugger

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I've got the "hello-world" app running via `phonegap serve` and I'm trying to attach the remote debugger you get with Chrome to see why it stops working when I start using Webpack.

So far I've done the following:

- Phonegap 4.2.0-0.26.0/Cordova 4.3.0
- `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` in AndroidManifest.xml
- `target=android-19` in project.properties
- Chrome v42.0.2311.135
- Enabled USB Debugging on the phone & plugged it in.
- Using Lollipop 5.1
- I've configured my webview for debugging [as described](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews)

but when I look at `chrome://inspect` I can only see Chrome, not my app with it's webview.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot attach the Phonegap Dev App to Chrome/Safari's WebView inspector.

*"Another issue is that you cannot use remote debugging with it. By that I mean Safari Remote Debugging or Chrome Remote Debugging."* - [Raymond Camben's Blog](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/04/21/PhoneGap-Developer-App)

Comment: However it's still possible to use [weinre](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/tools/weinre/)

Answer (score 0):

To use remote debugging in Phonegap you need:

- version 3.3 or higher
- `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` or higher in AndroidManifest.xml
- `target=android-19` or higher In project.properties
- version of desktop Chrome should be newer than the version of the webview (current version is 42.0.2311.138)

Please note that remote debugging is automatically enabled as long as it's a debug build (it's turned off in --release builds).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question to clarify I've already tried the things you suggest. Not sure how to check my WebView versions though?

Comment: You can check in `System Settings > Apps > Android System WebView > version`

Answer (score 0):

There is a static method [WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)) which you can use in order to control web debugging for all your WebViews in the app.

Comment: Do you actually have any WebView instances in your app when you are trying to connect your debugger? Nothing will appear unless you have created at least one instance. If, like you say, you can see Chrome in `chrome://inspect`, then the only culprit is your app.

Comment: You know what, that's a good question. I'm using the [Phonegap Dev app](http://app.phonegap.com/) which of course won't use any of the Android settings in the project. I wonder if the dev app a) uses Webviews, and b) has the debug enabled.

Comment: *"Another issue is that you cannot use remote debugging with it. By that I mean Safari Remote Debugging or Chrome Remote Debugging."* Dammit. That's the whole point of this, I want to set some breakpoints and work out why my js doesn't work when webpacked, works fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to debug apps built with Phonegap Build using the Chrome inspector.

First, make sure your widget tag contains xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

```
<widget 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="me.app.id" 
    version="1.0.0">
```

Then add the following

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
     <application android:debuggable="true" />
</gap:config-file>
```

It works for me on Nexus 5, Phonegap 3.7.0.

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
```

Build the app in Phonegap Build, install the APK, connect the phone to the USB, enable USB debugging on you phone then visit chrome://inspect.

I didn't have to specify the android-minSdkVersion, neither android-targetSdkVersion in the config.xml.

Source:
https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/learning-center/configuration/